# How to make sure only my app can insert data into the DB?

Tags: php, ios, mysql, api, oauth-2.0

**The problem**

I am developing the back-end for a iOS app. One of the endpoint allows the app to insert data into the database, e.g. `register-user.php`.

The app calls the API with certain parameters (e.g., username and password), the server performs certain operations (e.g., salt and hash the password) and then store everything on the database.

**The question**

How can I make sure only the app can actually call the API and insert data into the database?

I looked into `SSL` certificates and `OAuth2` but they don't seem to apply here (unless I profoundly misunderstood them).

Comment: You can encrypt the traffic & app, but ultimately if someone wants to crack your app and use the API they probably will. (which also means any secret keys you have on your app will be known)

Comment: Then pass a key known only to the app, in every api call which should be verified before being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Pass some token or auth/pwd to the api. Not the user's password, another pass that you keep on your app.
Also HTTPS is needed to avoid sniffing.

Is this a test question? You're the second person to ask the same, and both of you seem to dislike TLS/SSL for some unknown reason.

Comment: Hi @Voro, the reason why I am concerned about using SSL or any authentication token is that it would have to be hard-coded into the app so that if someone can access the source code of the application that person can also send valid API requests to the back-end.

Comment: I understand your concerns about hard-coding the token. However, it has nothing to do with SSL/TLS.